# Trying to bind a gridview via server mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gridview, devexpress

Im using `Devexpress` to develop a `WinForms` application with a grid. I dont want to load all registers of the grid in memory, but instead, just few (10 or 15 i.e), but i cannot find how to properly do that. I know that `Devexpress` shows some ways to do that, but i cant find any working example of this.

*Ps: Im using Oracle 11 as database.*

In these example they´re showing this showcase using LinqToSQL classes:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4057

But i do that and it works, but not as expected, becouse the grid is loading all the 500 registers once, with a scrollbar.

I tried this one as well using EntityFramework Server mode, but the result is the same as above:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8601

I would like to know how can I page the grid showing the number of rows that i want per page, and when i change the page, the database is consulted again.

The DbContext class:

```
  public partial class TestContext : DbContext
 {
    public TestContext()
        : base("name=TestContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModel{ get; set; }
}
```

The MainForm with the devexpress gridView:

```
 public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        entityServerModeSource1.QueryableSource = new TestContext().TestModel;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you are incorrectly understand the Server Mode concepts. The main idea of the Server Mode is that the grid control automatically loads data in small portions, on demand. No "paging" needed at all in this mode. E.g. when the grid starts, it loads and displays the first portion of data from the data store to fill the visible area. Then, as an end-user scrolls the grid, when the last record of the loaded subset is reached, the grid requests the data store to return a subsequent section of data.

> But i do that and it works, but not as expected, becouse the grid is loading all the 500 registers once, with a scrollbar.

Regarding the scroll-bars behavior it means, that grid will use some kind of "placeholders" for unloaded records and will automatically load all needed data from data source when the scroll-bars position is changed and data should be really displayed. This process can be synchronous or asynchronous.

Please take a look at the [Server Mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398) article to learn the basic Server Mode concepts.
Please take a look at the [Regular Binding Mode vs Regular Server Mode vs Instant Feedback Mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2991) to learn more about the differences between the synchronous and asynchronous data binding modes.

P.S. You can bind the grid control to any data easily, using the [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16633)  that dramatically simplifies the process of binding a data-aware DevExpress control (such as GridControl or TreeList) to a data source.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was very clarifing to me. But now that I understand the concept, i would like to have sure when, and where the database is being calling. And i cannot figure out how to do it, i mean, not point to breakpoint in this event.

Comment: @ggui It is not quite clear to me why you need to know this information because the XtraGrid is managed all this stuff itself. Anyway you can use specialized tools (SQL Profiler)

Comment: i understand your point but i would like to get the queries generated because ill need to use some of them in other scenario.